# getting new results with universes

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

One remarkable thing about introducing a universe U (or many universes) into Martin-Lof Type Theory is that it allows us to show that certain types are inhabited that we would not otherwise be able to show are inhabited. Moreover, this can be the case when the type in question contains no reference to U, but is a type we could have written down prior to introducing universes. For example, $\neg (\top = \perp)$ and $\neg (0=1)$ are not provable without universes in MLTT, but easily proved with universes. This gives a very good argument for universes, if our goal is to formalize mathematics.

But suppose we consider MLTT without natural number types, Booleans, finite types, or W types -- suppose that the only basic types we have are identity types, the empty type, and structureless dependent types obeying no particular laws. By structureless dependent types, I mean types with formation rules like
$$\vdash A \mbox{ type}$$
$$x:A \vdash B(x)\mbox{ type}$$
and so on, but no introduction, elimination or computation rules. (Think of the kind of type theory in which one has a Curry-Howard Correspondence with first order or higher order inuitionistic logic.) Call this 'minimal MLTT' (if there is already established terminology here, I would be happy to learn it.)

My question is what the effect of adding universes to minimal MLTT is. Certainly, one gets the effect of being able to construct functions 'polymorphic' in character, e.g. identity functions over all types in $U$. Along with this, one also gets new types. But when it comes to types one had already before introducing universes, does anything new become provable, like in the full MLTT case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you really mean when you say $\lnot(\top = \bot)$ is not provable without universes.  For example, for me the natural proof of that is: assume $\top = \bot$.  Then since $\top$ holds, by substitution (or ${=}E$), that implies $\bot$ holds also.  Where does that argument use universes?

Comment: (1) There is an old argument that goes back to Jan Smith that one cannot prove *any* claim of the form $\neg (s =_A t)$ in MLTT without universes. (2) Your argument is very terse, and I think fleshing it out would show the error. What, for example, do you mean by `$\top$ holds', and how exactly do you show that $\neg (\top = \perp)$ follows from it?

Comment: The slightly fleshed out argument would be: $\top = \bot \vdash \top$ by ${\top}I$, and $\top = \bot \vdash \top = \bot$ by assumption.  Therefore, $\top = \bot \vdash \bot$ by ${=}E$, so $\vdash \lnot (\top = \bot)$ (by either ${\rightarrow}I$ or ${\lnot}I$ depending on the exact definition and rules for $\lnot$).

Comment: I don't yet see which rules you are using. On the right hand side of $\top = \perp \ \vdash \top$, what is $\top$? Is it a type? An abbreviation of $\top: \mbox{Bool}$? Same question for $\top = \perp$ on the left hand side. And what version of =E are you using?

Comment: Also, from section 1 of Smith 'THE INDEPENDENCE OF PEANO'S FOURTH AXIOM FROM MARTIN-LOF'S TYPE THEORY WITHOUT UNIVERSES': 'I will use the method of Hilbert and Ackermann on Martin-Lof's type theory without universes to show that $\neg$Eq(A, a, b) cannot be derived without universes for any type A and any objects a and b of type A.'

Comment: In Coq-like notation for example, that proof would amount to something like: `(fun e : True = False => match e in (True = T) return T with | eq_refl => I end) : ~(True = False)` (where `I` is the canonical element of `True`).

Comment: I don't know enough about Coq to say, but some use of universes is presumably being hidden by the Coq formalism. I don't see any way to translate the idea of your proof into a proof in MLTT without universes.

Comment: $¬(⊥ = ⊤)$ cannot be *stated* in MLTT without universes, because $⊥$ and $⊤$ are types. To get them as the indices of an identity type, you need a type that contains (codes for) them. It's possible to design things differently, so that universes are not required, but universes are how MLTT allows you to write things like this at all.

Comment: Suppose you define $a =_A b$ as $\forall P : A \to Type, Pa \rightarrow Pb$, $\top$ as $\forall P : Type, P \rightarrow P$, and $\bot$ as $\forall P : Type, P$.  Then I would think $\lambda e : \top =_{Type} \bot . e (\lambda T . T) (\lambda P . \lambda x . x)$ would be of type $\lnot(\top = \bot)$.

Comment: Writing $A \rightarrow Type$ is just the way of writing universes in MLTT. Unless you have universes, $A \rightarrow Type$ doesn't make sense in MLTT.

Comment: Note that this question is now answered by https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614298/sum-types-in-mltt-without-universes/4614313#4614313